# Android accessibility service - Clearing an EditText

Tags: android

I am trying to insert text inside an EditText using android's `AccessibilityService`.
Currently, I am doing something like:

```
textnode.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_FOCUS);
ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", "DATA" );
clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
textnode.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_PASTE);
```

My problem is that if there is some text present inside the `EditText`, the new text is appended to it, whereas I want it replaced. I can't find any way to clear the text in the `EditText` from inside the accessibility service.

I feel as if I am missing something since this should be an easy task.
Please tell me how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 5):

I had to use some kind of a hack. 
Basically, it selects the text in the `EditText` and pastes the new text over it.
In my case, I had to replace a single word, so I just had to select the first word
Here's the code:

```
Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
arguments.putInt(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ARGUMENT_MOVEMENT_GRANULARITY_INT,
                    AccessibilityNodeInfo.MOVEMENT_GRANULARITY_WORD);
arguments.putBoolean(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ARGUMENT_EXTEND_SELECTION_BOOLEAN,
                    true);
textnode.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_PREVIOUS_AT_MOVEMENT_GRANULARITY,
                    arguments);
ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", "NEWDATA");
clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
usernode.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_PASTE);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this，hope can help you

```
Bundle arguments = new Bundle();   

arguments.putCharSequence(
AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ARGUMENT_SET_TEXT_CHARSEQUENCE,
"your info");

nodeInfo.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SET_TEXT, arguments);
```

Comment: You should really add some explanation as to why this code should work - you can also add comments in the code itself - in its current form, it does not provide any explanation which can help the rest of the community to understand what you did to solve/answer the question.

Comment: thank,but i see the doc in the source,no only for api>=21,

Comment: Action that sets the text of the node. Performing the action without argument, using <code>
      null</code> or empty {@link CharSequence} will clear the text. This action will also put the
      cursor at the end of text.

        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putCharSequence(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ARGUMENT_SET_TEXT_CHARSEQUENCE,
            "android");
        info.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SET_TEXT, arguments);

Answer (score -1):

Just call setText on EditText and pass in an empty char before you do the paste - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
editText.setText("", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
```

Comment: I have to do this from an accessibility service. The edit text is general, like it can be any edit text in any application. I don't think I can use setText like that